# Linux path utils

Tags: linux, delphi, filesystems

Im working on windows, and I want to prepare linux path string. There are many useful mathods in TPath, so I made this (it doesn't work):

```
uses
{$DEFINE POSIX}
    System.IOUtils;
{$UNDEF POSIX}
type
    TPosixPath = TPath;
```

I wanted do same thing with System.SysUtils to use e.g IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter but both don't work.
Any idea how use those units in linux way? Or another idea for manipulate linux strings paths using existing units?

Comment: @Victoria asker wants to work with POSIX paths on a non POSIX platform

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That does not work because the POSIX conditional is used when the unit is **compiled** and not when it is **used**.

In order to prepare a POSIX path on a non-POSIX system you are going to have to prepare some bespoke methods. You can use the IOUtils unit as a guide although be warned that unit has a few wrinkles. Try not to transcribe any design flaws in your own variants.

Comment: There is any chance to cheat it by using helpers?

Comment: Why helpers? Don't ask for a solution using a particular feature. You don't care about how the problem is solved. You want a solution. Anyway, the first paragraph explains why the IOUtils unit cannot do what you want.

Comment: In other words: the POSIX parts of these units will only be compiled when you are using a compiler (target) that compiles to iOS, Android, macOS or Linux. They were not compiled in when they were compiled for Windows.